# How to add exercise points to package exercisebank?

Tags: exercisebank

Exercisebank has in version 0.2.0 no build-in way of handling points. How do you add a point system to the part problems in [`exercisebank`](https://ctan.org/pkg/exercisebank)? E.g. In an exercise-file, I would like to do

```
\begin{problem}
  \addpoints{2}
  problem description
\end{problem}
```

and now it should show in the part problem header. E.g. `(1c) 2p:`.

I'd also like a command that could be used at the end that shows the accumulated points. E.g.

`\totalpoints`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: Point system is now implemented in [`exercisebank`](https://ctan.org/pkg/exercisebank):

#### In your exercisefile, say `testexercise.tex`:

```
\begin{problem}
    \nextproblem{points=2}
    Problem containing \makeatletter\exb@currentPoints\makeatother~points
\end{problem}
\begin{problem}
    \addpoints{points=1}
    Problem containing \makeatletter\exb@currentPoints\makeatother~points
\end{problem}
\begin{problem}
    \ppheader
    Problem containing no points
\end{problem}
```

You can access the total number of points in the `\totalpoints` macro.

---

## Previous answer:

This is an upcoming feature, but I don't know exactly when I'll get around to do it. Here I'll present a workaround that **would not work if you're using e.g. `\select` or `\exclude`**. I'll write below how you'd make that work:

This code makes a counter and a placeholder for the points:

#### `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exercisebank}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\makeatletter
% Make a counter for accumulating points
\newcounter{problempoints}
% For readability, defining
\let\totalpoints\theproblempoints
% \currentPoints is a placeholder for
% the number of points the current part problem has
\gdef\currentPoints{0}
% Disable the default part problem header made by exercisebank
\exercisebanksetup{part problem header={\relax}}
% Make a new command to insert part problem header
% (inspired by the default found on page 10 in the manual):
\def\ppheader{%
  \leavevmode%
  \smash{%
    \llap{%
      {\large\textbf{(\theproblemcounter\alph{partproblemcounter})}}%
      % if \currentPoints contains 0, \currentPoints aren't printed.
      \ifnum\currentPoints=\z@\else\currentPoints p\fi~}}\ignorespaces%
}
% Reset \currentPoints, so that if no points are set in the next, nothing would be added
\At\EndPartproblem{\gdef\currentPoints{0}}
% Make a new command that sets the current points and increases the total-counter
\newcommand\addpoints[1]{%
  \gdef\currentPoints{#1}%
  \addtocounter{problempoints}{#1}%
  \ppheader
}
\makeset{test}{testexercise}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  \buildset{test}
\end{document}
```

#### Now, the `testexercise.tex`:

```
\begin{problem}
    \addpoints{2}
    Problem containing \currentPoints~points
\end{problem}
\begin{problem}
    \addpoints{1}
    Problem containing \currentPoints~points
\end{problem}
\begin{problem}
    \ppheader
    Problem containing no points
\end{problem}
```

Which would produce what you

---

This is a Q&A-question. I've gotten multiple inquiries in regards to this on github and email, so I decided to make a Q&A here.

Answer (score 2):

Works fine here. I modified the code a bit, so you have the points on the right side with a small rule like in xsim. `Needs \usepackage{marginnote}`.

**The changed part of the code looks like this:**

```
.....
\def\ppheader{%
    \leavevmode%
    \smash{%
        \llap{%
            {\large\textbf{\theproblemcounter\alph{partproblemcounter})}}%
            % if \currentPoints contains 0, \currentPoints aren't printed.
            %\ifnum\currentPoints=\z@\else\currentPoints p\fi~}}\ignorespaces%
            \ifnum\currentPoints=\z@\else\marginnote{\rule{1cm}{.5pt}~/\currentPoints P.}
            \fi}}\ignorespaces%
}
....
```

The only thing is, that `\totalpoints` has to run at last. My exams start usually with a titlepage showing the total points sum (`\totalpoints`). But this does not work here.